# Material UI v5 selector opening list as horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am migrating a codebase from Material-Ui v4 to Material-Ui v5. After doing this, the `Select` component started to open horizontally instead of vertically as the image below:

[image]

This is the code:

```
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";
import {
  FormControl
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled as styledMui } from "@mui/material/styles";

const PlanSelect = styledMui(Select)({
  fieldset: {
    legend: {
      width: "unset",
    },
  },
});
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  planSelect: {
    float: "right",
    width: "350px",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
}));

...
const CustomComponent = ()=>{
   ...
   return(
     ...
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.planSelect}>
          <PlanSelect
              value={productId}
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setProductId(value)}>
               <MenuItem value="standard">Option A</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="pro">Option B</MenuItem>
           </PlanSelect>
       </FormControl>
)
```

Classes:

How can I make the options list from the Select to open vertically as Material-Ui v4 ?

Comment: Is it easy to create a codesandbox replicating the issue? I tried to do it with the provided code but nothing that helped understand what the issue is.

Comment: Can you show us your class classes.planSelect ?

Comment: @Virthuss I've just updated the question to include classes.planSelect's definition

Comment: @Akis I tried to create a small sandbox trying to replicate the same issue, but unfortunately, everything works fine on the sandbox :/ which leads me to believe that this is happening due to some conflict between libraries and existing configurations on the codebase. This is a big React application

Comment: @MarcosPauloJúnior I know what you mean and I agree with you. Can you share a list of the other css libraries you are using? Maybe it will make it easier to identify where the conflict comes from.